# Is there any Apache Web Server Module that can intercept requests and prints the body

Tags: post, apache2, httprequest

I am looking for an Apache module that can intercept POST requests and print the "body" of the POST requests.

If there aren't any modules for these kind of situations, is there any other method that can help?

Note: I am using Apache2 as a web server, in windows operating system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for mod_dumpio :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Comment: I might have been too brief, to be more specific, I need to get the raw data (<body> part) of the POST request.

Comment: Well, dumpio will log everything that goes by the Apache HTTPd server, including the raw body part of the POST request. Do you mean that you are looking for something that logs only the body part ?

Comment: Well, if dumps the raw body part it might work for me, I have to do is filter it then, must try it. The thing is, I want to see the html variables (Ex: radio buttons, texfields, comboboxes etc.). If dumpio can give me these, its perfect.

Comment: It seems that it works, but does this also work for responses as well?